# How to disable samsung multi window tray bar for my application

Tags: android, multi-window

I have a requirement where i need to remove Samsung multi window tray bar because some of my application control is behind it.

[image: Samsung Tray Bar]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung has not provided any api to completely disable or remove multi window tray bar for our application.

Samsung has only provided api to make our application compatible with multi window.

**Reference**

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#multiwindow